# Can the "user secrets" file be declare as required for an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core

Using the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration package, I have the following line in my Program.cs file:

`config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>(optional: false);`

With a populated secrets.json file present, this line works as presumed.  Alternatively, I would assume that a missing secrets.json file should trigger an exception of some sort, since I marked it as required; however, no exception is thrown.

Is this to be expected?  My ultimate goal is to give developers an obvious indicator if they pull a project out of source control and attempt to run it without also having created a correlated secrets file.

Comment: Okay this is really weird and could be a bug in the SDK potentially. I can confirm it does not throw though the docs say it should. If you look at the built configuration with the debugger, you can actually see that the user secrets provider has Optional: true even though it was set to false :\

Comment: AddJsonFile does throw if you set optional to false (or leave it out since optional is false by default).

Comment: It might be here actually: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1ade5327c94d1b67622705b9f9b76fac4b49e677/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/src/UserSecretsConfigurationExtensions.cs#L119. Note the optional parameter is never used in the function. I recommend raising an issue on the dotnet/runtime repo and link to this question.

Comment: It looks like it _is_ used, on line [137](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1ade5327c94d1b67622705b9f9b76fac4b49e677/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/src/UserSecretsConfigurationExtensions.cs#L137) of the linked code. It's only checking that the project includes an ID, which you've said it does. Line [192](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1ade5327c94d1b67622705b9f9b76fac4b49e677/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/src/UserSecretsConfigurationExtensions.cs#L192) shows the file itself is always considered optional.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback.  I guess the question is: should the file itself be considered optional?  My opinion would be no, but I suppose there could be an underlying reason why it was implemented that way.  Regardless, I have followed the above suggestion and posted an issue on GitHub.